# Create native iOS guided-selling app using BigMachines API and SFDC integration?

Tags: api, salesforce1-platform

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a native iOS guided selling app (ask a few questions to get the right set of products or configurations) using just BigMachines API, and with SFDC integration? This would be completely customized UI, rather than using components from BigMachines or SF.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible. Your app can use the [SFDC iOS SDK](https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS) to authenticate to SFDC, and the iOS SOAP API client of your choice to interface with BigMachines' SOAP API. You need not use any UI components from SFDC with the possible exception of the login webview.

Comment: Thanks, @Jonathan - do you know if the BigMachines SOAP API is robust enough to return rules and/or specific product configurations based on a set of input parameters? My fear is that their API would be superficial at best, based on what I've seen of their Parts API, etc.

Comment: Can't say I know the first thing about their API, sorry, other than that it exists. :) Assuming it is a reasonably standard SOAP API you should have no problems working with it on iOS.